# Conversion of table to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to **convert** a **table to** a **data frame**.

Example:

```
tbl <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(4L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
c("1", "2", "3", "4"), colNames = c("2013 3", "2014 12")), .Names = c("", "colNames")), class = "table")

colNames
     2013 3 2014 12
1      1       1
2      0       0
3      0       0
4      0       0
```

Conversion to data frame leads to a completely **different data structure**. Why ?

```
as.data.frame(tbl)

Var1 colNames Freq
1    1   2013 3    1
2    2   2013 3    0
3    3   2013 3    0
4    4   2013 3    0
5    1  2014 12    1
6    2  2014 12    0
7    3  2014 12    0
8    4  2014 12    0
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a dup @Jilber Urbina since the OP wants to know _why_

Comment: From `?as.data.frame.table` : "The as.data.frame method for objects inheriting from class "table" can be used to convert the array-based representation of a contingency table to a data frame containing the classifying factors and the corresponding entries (the latter as component named by responseName). " which I think  just means it is a design choice. (and  that said, it doesn't really answer the "why")

Comment: Not clear what "why" means here. What alternative is there that would behave consistently for tables with more or fewer than two dimensions, like `table(mtcars[9:11])`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the *precise* reason as to *"why"* is that this is the source code for `as.data.frame.table` (just enter that name in an R console with no other punctuation to see this in the console):

```
function(x, row.names = NULL, ..., responseName = "Freq", 
         stringsAsFactors = TRUE, sep = "", base = list(LETTERS))  {

  ex <- quote(
    data.frame(
      do.call(
        "expand.grid", 
        c(
          dimnames(provideDimnames(x, sep = sep, base = base)), 
          KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE, 
          stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors)
      ), 
      Freq = c(x), row.names = row.names)
  )
  names(ex)[3L] <- responseName
  eval(ex)

}
```

Ultimately, what you have with:

```
tbl <- structure(
  c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
  .Dim = c(4L, 2L), 
  .Dimnames = structure(
    list(
      c("1", "2", "3", "4"), 
      colNames = c("2013 3", "2014 12")
    ), 
    .Names = c("", "colNames")
  ), 
  class = "table"
)
```

is an `integer` vector with some attributes. When you type `tbl` and hit `<ENTER>` in an R console it's calling `print.table()` (enter `print.table` with no other punctuation in an R console to see its source) it goes through some hoops to print what you see as a "rectangular" data structure.

To get your desired result, just do what the print function ultimately does (in a not-as-straightforward-way):

```
as.data.frame.matrix(tbl)
```

or using tidyverse idioms:

```
as.data.frame(tbl) %>% 
  tidyr::spread(colNames, Freq)
##   Var1 2013 3 2014 12
## 1    1      1       1
## 2    2      0       0
## 3    3      0       0
## 4    4      0       0
```

Comment: @hbmstr: Solution successfully tested on multiple matrices